# Proof by induction on First Order Formula

Tags: induction, first-order-logic

I am confused about how to prove that $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models  \varphi \leftrightarrow (\mathcal{A}, i') \models  \varphi$ given that two interpretations $i$ and $i'$ agree on all free variables in $\varphi$. Do I need to prove for each true form (below) of the language? And how I do this?

> Let $\mathcal{A} \in STRUC[\tau]$ be a structure and $\tau$ a
>   vocabulary. We can inductively define wether a formula $\varphi \in
> > \mathcal{L}(\tau)$ is true in $(\mathcal{A}, i)$:
>
> - $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models t_{1} = t_{2} \leftrightarrow i(t_{1}) = i(t_{2})$
> - $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models R_{j}(t_{1}, ..., t_{a_{j}}) \leftrightarrow \langle i(t_{1}),...,i(t_{a_{j}}) \rangle \in
>   R_{j}^{\mathcal{A}}$
> - $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models \neg \varphi \leftrightarrow$ it is not the case that $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models \varphi$
> - $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models \varphi \wedge \psi \leftrightarrow (\mathcal{A}, i) \models \varphi$ and $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models \psi$
> - $(\mathcal{A}, i) \models (\exists x) \varphi \leftrightarrow$ $($there exists $a \in |\mathcal{A}|(\mathcal{A,i,a/x})) \models
>   \varphi$,
>     where $(i, a/x)(y) = \begin{Bmatrix}
>   i(y) & \text{ if } y \neq x\\ 
>   a & \text{ if } y = x
>   \end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: What do you mean by "agree on all free variables"? Is $i(x)=i'(x)$ for $x$ free in $\varphi$?

Comment: As $i : V \rightarrow |\mathcal{A}|$, where $V$ is a subset of VAR (free variables) and $|\mathcal{A}|$ is the universe of $\mathcal{A}$, I think the book means that $V = V'$.